# jQuery - can't set css propery in ajax callback function

Tags: css, jquery, callback, background-color

I'm trying to get an jquery ajax callback function to update the background colour of a table cell, but I can't get it to work.

I have the following code (which produces no errors in Firebug):

```
$(".tariffdate").click(function () {
   var property_id = $('#property_id').attr("value");
   var tariff_id = $('#tariff_id').attr("value");
   var tariff_date = $(this).attr("id");
   $.post("/admin/properties/my_properties/booking/edit/*", { property_id: property_id, tariff_id: tariff_id, tariff_date:  tariff_date },
function(data){
   var bgcol = '#' + data;
   $(this).css('background-color',bgcol);
   alert("Color Me: " + bgcol);
});
```

I've added the alert just to confirm I'm getting the expected data back (a 6 digit hexadecimal code), and I am - but the background of my table cell stubbornly refuses to change.

All the table cells have the class .tariffdate but also have individual ID.

As a test, I tried creating a hover function for that class:

```
$(".tariffdate").hover(function () {
   $(this).css('background-color','#ff0000');
});
```

The above works fine - so I'm really confused as to why my callback function is not functioning. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the AJAX completed handler the instance of `this` is changed to the ajax object.  You'll need to save the instance of `this` to an object and use that object.  For example:

```
$(".tariffdate").click(function () {
   var property_id = $('#property_id').attr("value");
   var tariff_id = $('#tariff_id').attr("value");
   var tariff_date = $(this).attr("id");
   var tariff = $(this);
   $.post("/admin/properties/my_properties/booking/edit/*", 
      { property_id: property_id, tariff_id: tariff_id, tariff_date:  tariff_date },
      function(data) {
         var bgcol = '#' + data;
         tariff.css('background-color',bgcol);
         alert("Color Me: " + bgcol);
      }
   );
});
```

Comment: You're a star - that was the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check what the "this" variable is in you ajax callback function. I suspect that it's not referring to .tariffdate